# Calculating the real and reactive power of a transmission line

Tags: generator, transmission-line, reactive-power, real-power

I have a single machine connected to an infinite bus with the following parameters:

- Sending end power = 3.75MW
- RL=5.18 ohms
- XL=130 ohms
- VS (Generator bus)=161kV
- VR (Infinite bus)=161kV
- Sending end voltage angle (delta) = 0.01877 (Angle which allows 3.75MW to be transferred)

Using these I want to calculate the amount of reactive power sent by the sending end as well.

I calculated it first without factoring in the line resistance (RL=0) Then got the result for Q as : **35.24kVAR**

Next I calculated it with the line resistance factored in Then got the result for Q as: **-114.77kVAR**

When the line resistance is factored in, the answers for reactive power vary immensely. And when the resistance is factored in, the sign of Q is negative indicating the generator bus is absorbing VARS which doesn't seem to make sense.

Why are they so different? What am I doing wrong?

The equations I used are [here](https://www.docdroid.net/1BloEij/angle-final.pdf.html)

I derived these equations using Matlab to do the algebra, so it hopefully should be correct :)

Comment: perhaps your assumptions are wrong.  You must conjugate match the impedance by phase shift but also add voltage for line R loss.    try adding V²/W voltage to Vs and adjust phase lead to 0.538 degrees (using power per phase not total)

Comment: Thanks for the response Tony.

I didn't get what you meant by "conjugate match the impedance by phase shift"?

and how did you calculate 0.538rads and why do i need to adjust it by this much?

Comment: www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ewa/ch13.pdf I said degrees

Comment: Apologies i misread. Ill have a look at that link.
Thanks

Comment: did u not understand the voltage loss part?  Conjugates use easy vector match with opposite reactance which is your phase with R +jX